# Send newsletter action - after saving simplenews node

Tags: emails

I would like to do the same thing that described here: http://drupal.org/node/1427246

So, I use drupal 7, simplenews, schedule, and import modules.

I want to import my simplenews nodes, and they have scheduled date and time to publish...

But the problem for me is there is no way to set "send newsletter" status for the newsletter nodes automatically. I should click on each and every node to approve it to send.

On the link above there is a solution:

> "Create a rule that is triggered when a node is inserted (update makes
>   no sense as you can't resend a newsletter, add a condition on the node
>   content type and then execute the Send newsletter action."

My question: how can I activate the "Send newsletter action". It is not appear on the list of available actions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable the simplenews_rules module which comes packaged with simplenews - this has the action for sending a newsletter defined:

```
'simplenews_rules_action_send' => array(
  'label' => t('Send newsletter'),
  'group' => t('Simplenews'),
  'parameter' => array(
    'node' => array(
      'type' => 'node',
      'label' => t('The newsletter node to be sent.'),
      'description' => t('The newsletter node that should be sent.'),
    )
  )
),
```

Comment: did enabling that answer your question?